# Can't add newline to body in flow sendEmail action

Tags: email, visual-workflow, text-template

I have a text template within a flow like this -

```
There has been an error with automation

Id - {!$Record.New_Id__c}

Error Message - {!ErrorText}
```

I'm using this text template as the body of an sendEmail action. I can't work out how to add newlines to the email body - it gets sent as one long string of text.

I've tried wrapping the text in <p></p> tags, using <br/>, using \r \n with both the 'view in plain text' and 'view in rich text' settings, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the sendEmail action from the sample flow pack?

It may be an issue with how the flow is interpreting the characters you're entering, you can try replacing all the `'\r'` or `'\n'` characters for the HtmlBody with `'<br />'` after you have already set up the email body as a string, like so:

```
HtmlBody.replace('\r\n','<br \>');
```

When working with the HtmlBody in Apex `<br>` works fine, so I think it's the front end of the flow not using the right characters. An example:

```
mail.setSubject('Example Email');
mail.setHtmlBody('Hi ' + Contact.FirstName + ',<br>' +'<br>' + 'Message continues 
here...');
```